# Web view Background trasparency

Tags: coronasdk

in `native.showWebPopup` we can use transparency on CSS to make the background transparent and see whats behind the webview but if i use `native.newWebView` the background is not transparent       is there a way to make it transparent just like the showWebPopup

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `webView.hasBackground = false`

Comment: Why this is not not documented in the official Corona SDK API Documentation?